# Software tool for practical XOR comparisons (ASCII and HEX)

Tags: encryption

A quiz 2 weeks ago on [UMCP](http://www.umd.edu/)'s [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) cryptography course had us use (and break) a modified [Vigenere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) cipher wherein ASCII characters where XOR'ed against a Hex secret key to create the cipher text.

Example:

```
Plaintext: "Cool!"
Hex key:    0x01 3F
Ciphertext: 0x62 50 6E 53 20
```

I did this one character at a time by looking at a binary/hex/ASCII conversion chart, but that's obviously not practical in the real world.

My question is **not** about the specific quiz question or the specific cipher, but rather how can one do these sorts of comparisons in a practical (i.e. non-manual) way?

**Is there a good tool for it (maybe something from [sectools.org](http://sectools.org/) or someplace like that)?**

Some way of using a Hex calculator? Do you have to write a custom C or Java program to handle it? I tried to Google it myself to no avail. I could write a Java class to handle it, but obviously, if there's a more robust tool written by someone smarter than me, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Cryptool](https://www.cryptool.org/en/), an open source project with the goal of teaching cryptography.

I am using Cryptool 2. It can e.g. calculate XOR results as shown below. Unfortunately it doesn't really work well with hexadecimal inputs, but still it's very nice and implements many crypto-functions.

[image: Cryptool screenshot]

Comment: Awesome! That will be very useful